# Can't format new SSHD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, install

I just got a new SSHD, but when I tried to put it in my early 2011 13" MBP and format it from a bootable drive, Disk Utility kept giving me the error message:

`could not mount disk0s2 with name (null) after erase`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to erase and format it, before you can mount it.

Comment: @IronCraftMan I know. I got that output as the result of telling it to erase and format, presumably as it was trying to mount itself after having been erased.